# Batch File to upload via FTP - 550 Permission Denied

Tags: windows, command-line, permissions, batch, ftp

I am trying to create a batch file that will upload a single file by FTP every time it is ran. Everything looks good in windows cmd. I get past the authentication of user name and password and after PUT it says 200 PORT command successful but the next line is 550 xmltest.xml: Permission denied.
When I run thru the steps manually in the cmd prompt I can upload it just fine and it takes without this error which leads me to believe it is within the batch file.

this is the bat file...

```
@echo off
echo user username> ftpcmd.dat
echo password>> ftpcmd.dat
echo bin /httpdocs/FOLDER/tools/locations/>> ftpcmd.dat
echo put C:\_ARTWORK\xmltest.xml>> ftpcmd.dat
echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat XXX.XXX.XX.XXX
del ftpcmd.dat
```

If anyone knows what I am doing wrong here please let me know.
thanks!